# Can we call this real prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm always flabbergasted by the way people try to force some form of classical inheritance into javascript. I have designed a method to inherit in some object b the prototype methods from object a, without adding prototype methods from object b to object a, *and* the possibility to use private variables from the object inherited from<sup>**1**</sup>. Now I'm curious: would you say this is really prototypal 'inheritance'? Is it a viable method? Are there pittfals to it?

Here's some example code:

```
Object.prototype.inheritsFrom = function(obj){
    var prototo   = this.prototype, 
        protofrom = obj.prototype;
    for (var l in protofrom) {
        if (protofrom.hasOwnProperty(l)){
            prototo[l] = protofrom[l];
        }
    }
}

function Obj1(){
    var const1 = 25;
    if (!Obj1.prototype.getConst1){
       Obj1.prototype.getConst1 = function(){
           return const1;
       }
    }
}

function Obj2(){
    var const2 = 50;
    if (!Obj2.prototype.getConst2){
       Obj2.prototype.getConst2 = function(){
           return const2;
       }
    }
    Obj2.inheritsFrom(Obj1);
}

var instanceA = new Obj1,
    instanceB = new Obj2;
```

Now `instanceA` contains method `getConst1`, `instanceB` contains methods `getConst1` and `getConst2`, as you can see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Xesj8/).

<sup>**1**</sup> By assigning the prototype methods *in* the constructor function, effectively using the closure created by that.

Comment: Don't know what to say. You extend the prototype of A with the methods in prototype of B. From an object point of view, A does not inherit from B, but from a conceptional point of view it does. It is probably annoying to write all this `if` clauses for a lot of methods ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not prototypical inheritance. In true prototypical inheritance, changes to the prototype appear in the objects that rely on that prototype. In your example, they don't, because they're only copied.

I'm not saying it may not be another useful form of inheritance for some situations, but it's not prototypical. In some sense I'm not even sure it's inheritance, although I think one could argue it either way and it doesn't really matter regardless.

Here's an example of adding to the prototype:

```
function Parent() {
}
Parent.prototype.foo = function() {
  display("foo!");
};

function Child() {
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();

var c = new Child();

display("[before] typeof c.foo === '" + typeof c.foo + "'");
// shows "[before] typeof c.foo === 'function'"
display("[before] typeof c.bar === '" + typeof c.bar + "'");
// shows "[before] typeof c.bar === 'undefined'"
display("Note that c.bar is currently undefined");

Parent.prototype.bar = function() {
  display("bar!");
};

display("[after] typeof c.bar === '" + typeof c.bar + "'");
// shows "[after] typeof c.bar === 'function'"
display("Now c.bar is a function");

c.foo();
c.bar();
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ebase5)

Note that this is not an obscure case. After all, your own code relies on changes to `Object.prototype` being reflected in the other things (`Function`) that have *already* derived from it.

---

**Off-topic**: **Strongly** recommend never adding anything to `Object.prototype`. It will break a huge amount of code that assumes that using `for..in` on a `{}` would yield no properties. Until you can reliably mark additions as non-enumerable (ECMAScript5 now provides a way to do that, but most implementations don't have it yet), just stay away from `Object.prototype`. Just a recommendation. Additionally, in your case, it doesn't make sense, because the `inheritsFrom` only works for `Function` instances, so you'd want to add it to `Function.prototype` instead (which is a lot less dangerous).

Comment: Thanks T.J. It's all experimental. I know the regular syntax for adding to the prototype, just wanted to try something else. And in real life I will not add to the Object prototype either. I think my experiment was not well thought through and isn't really usefull, so I'll discard it. The only idea I will keep is to have some private constant in the constructor by defining the prototype inside the constructor.

Comment: @KooiInc: Glad that was useful. Re the constant, that's basically a variation on private variables (just without a setter). If you find this general area interesting, three articles to read (disclosure: two are mine): [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) (Crockford), [Private Methods in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/private-methods-in-javascript.html) (me), and [Simple, Efficient Supercalls in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) (me). *(cont'd)*

Comment: @KooiInc: *(continuing)* I'm planning to redo the terminology on that last one, because it's actually prototypical inheritance, no need for the "class" terminology on it. Enjoy,